# Не шокай/шёкай мне тут!

Tags: орфография

Мы знаем, что правильно писать *чё*.

> Чё ты тявкнул?!

Но как правильно писать: *шо* или *шё*?

> Не шокай/шёкай мне тут!

> Шо/шё?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*— **Шо**?!*

*— Не **шокай** мне тут!*

**Пояснение**

**К примеру:**  *Одесситы, когда говорят по-русски, часто заменяют слово «что» на наречие «шо». На первый взгляд это может показаться ошибкой или неправильным употреблением слова, но это одна из особенностей местного диалекта. **«Шо»** в данном случае является разговорным вариантом слова **«что»** и употребляется в повседневном разговоре одесситов.* **[Источник](https://m-s13.ru/odessity-o-tom-cto-so-osobennosti-govora-i-frazeologiya/)**

1. В русской орфографии **звук О** в ударной позиции после шипящих может обозначаться **буквами О и Ё.**
2. Гласную первого ряда О можно считать  **основным вариантом**, а гласная Ё пишется **в двух случаях:** в корне слова с чередованием Е/Ё (шёпот/шептать) и в суффиксах и окончаниях глаголов и глагольных форм (решённый, решён).
3. Вариант "***шо, шокать"*** к исключениям не относится.

Comment: Просто мы же пишем *чё*, хотя веской причины нет.

Comment: Ты чё – это ты чего.  Здесь чередование Е/Ё в корне.